# Spring-WS WS-Security LDAP Authentication

Tags: authentication, spring-security, ldap, spring-ws, ws-security

I'm having trouble getting LDAP Authentication working with Spring-WS using LDAP user authentication.  I've found several examples of how to do this and several of them use different beans, some even write their own authenticators.  Unfortunately none seem to have all the necessary detail to get this working.  In addition, since there seem to be several different ways to get this working, I'm unsure of the best approach.  I've tried both the wss4j (apache) and xwss (sun) security providers and get similar results.  I know the ws-security piece is working (it works fine without the LDAP piece using the SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler) and even the ldap context is able to retrieve the user from the LDAP repository, but in the end, the password authentication fails.  Also, I don't see why it would matter, but I'm using Active Directory as my LDAP provider...

```
    <sws:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.controller.interceptors.EcrsPayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
            <property name="policyConfiguration" value="classpath:securityPolicy.xml" />
            <property name="callbackHandlers">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="authenticationHandler"/>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </sws:interceptors>

    <bean id="securityContextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
            <constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:389/DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=local"/>
            <property name="userDn" value="CN=user1,CN=Users,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=local"/>
            <property name="password" value="password1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
            <constructor-arg name="searchBase" value=""/>
            <constructor-arg name="searchFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
            <constructor-arg name="contextSource" ref="apacheContextSource"/>
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg name="contextSource" ref="apacheContextSource"/>
            <constructor-arg name="groupSearchBase" value="CN=Users"/>
            <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="CN"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService">
            <constructor-arg name="userSearch" ref="ldapUserSearch"/>
            <constructor-arg name="authoritiesPopulator" ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringDigestPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="ldapUserDetailsService"/>
    </bean>
```

*securityPolicy.xml*:

```
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config" dumpMessages="true" >
    <xwss:RequireTimestamp maxClockSkew="60" timestampFreshnessLimit="300"/>
    <xwss:RequireUsernameToken passwordDigestRequired="false" nonceRequired="true"/>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

Comment: also, here is my securityPolicy.xml 

<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config" dumpMessages="true" >
    <xwss:RequireTimestamp maxClockSkew="60" timestampFreshnessLimit="300"/>
    <xwss:RequireUsernameToken passwordDigestRequired="false" nonceRequired="true"/>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I found...

```
    <sws:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.controller.interceptors.EcrsPayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
            <property name="policyConfiguration" value="classpath:securityPolicy.xml" />
            <property name="callbackHandlers">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="authenticationHandler"/>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </sws:interceptors>

    <bean id="authenticationHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authManager" />
    </bean>

    <s:authentication-manager id="authManager">
        <s:authentication-provider ref='ldapAuthProvider'/>
    </s:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
       <constructor-arg>
           <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
               <constructor-arg ref="securityContextSource" />
               <property name="userSearch" ref="ldapUserSearch"/>
           </bean>
       </constructor-arg>
       <constructor-arg name="authoritiesPopulator" ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityContextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
            <constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:389/DC=xxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=local"/>
            <property name="userDn" value="CN=xxxxxx,CN=xxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxxx,DC=local"/>
            <property name="password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
            <constructor-arg name="searchBase" value=""/>
            <constructor-arg name="searchFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
            <constructor-arg name="contextSource" ref="securityContextSource"/>
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg name="contextSource" ref="securityContextSource"/>
            <constructor-arg name="groupSearchBase" value="CN=Users"/>
            <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="CN"/>
    </bean>
```